# I would like to use a parameter for the table name. The table names can be presented to the user from a database view.

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I would like to use a parameter for the table name. I have an application that creates several new tables each month. I therefore need the table name to be sent into CR via a parameter. The fields for the tabkes are always identical. I can present a list (view) from the database to the end user that would display a user friendly name for the table, when the user selects the instance they want I then have the table name I want to report from.

Comment: Tables are getting created dynamically but what is the idea and what exactly is the report requirement?

Comment: Siva, Each new table creates a new set of records over time. The more recent sets are the ones the users are more interested in. I would like to add a Crystal report to the applications that simple sees the extra tables (and their rows) as they are created and the rows propagated. I could potentially create a nightly job that dynamically creates a fresh view. I do have a table that has a user friendly name and the table names hence the preference to present this to the users for selection and pass the table as a parameter.

Comment: I don't think it is feasable with crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is possible. Even if your tables have the same structure, the field names will ultimately be different. Let's say you have a {table1.field1} in your report. Now you want to run the report from table2 instead of table1. So your field now would have to become {table2.field1}. Does that make sense? I think a better approach might be to try stored procedures that will create the fields you need so the field names won't change.

Comment: Campagnolo - thanks that does make sense. I will have to figure out some way of creating a view that appears to concatinate the tables as they are created.